# When importing excel file in r from url, date format is character

Tags: r

I am importing an excel file, from url. It contains date format, but after importing it is character '35095'.

How to convert it to date format. I am using the following code :

```
as.Date('35095', format="%B/%d/%Y")
```

but output is NA.

For importing data  I am using code:

```
library(rio)
data = rio::import(url)
```

Comment: Just convert it to as.numeric and then you can use this: `as.Date(as.numeric(x), format="%Y-%m-%d", origin="1899-12-30")`, You can find explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51618600/convert-multiple-columns-of-numeric-data-to-dates-in-r/51618720#51618720

Comment: or use `readxl::read_excel()` and set the `col_types()`-argument to `date` for the specified columns... or use `openxlsx::convertToDate()` on te imported data.

Comment: @Wimpel `openxlsx::convertToDate()` works, thanks